# Volume of the solid generated by revolving

Tags: calculus

I am required to find the volume of the solid generated by revolving the region bounded by the graphs $y=2x^2$ , $y=0$, $x=0$, about the $y-axis$. Problem is, the fact that $x$ and/or $y$ is $0$ gives me the impression that it can't be solved because I've never come across such a scenario. Is it true that it's unsolvable? Why or why not?

Comment: $x=a$ and $y=b$ are often given to get a closed surface. The three graphs you have given doesn't form a closed surface. Even more, since $y=2x^2$ is a parabola, the surface is infinite, thus the volume is infinite. Is there something missing or wrong? If it was $x = 2$, then the surface would be the region between the $x$-axis and the parabola, for $x$ between $0$ and $2$.

Comment: @AlainRemillard, I was thinking the same thing, too! I suspect the question was just typed wrong. I'll change it to $x=2$ and proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, let's revolve the curve around the y=0 axis.  The curve is a parabola; revolving it around the surface creates a bowl.

Ok, now we're going to cut the bowl at the x=0 and y=0 planes.  We cut it off at x=0.  This is like cutting the bowl in half.

Then we cut it off at y=0.  And here, the problem becomes ambiguous.  Option 1: We cut it off so that everything less than and including the plane is part of the volume of interest.  If this is the case, there is only one point included.  Therefore, the volume is 0.  Option 2:  everything above the plane is included.  Since the bowl starts at 0, it's like we placed the bowl on the ground. That leaves us with half a paraboloid going up to infinity.  Since there are no other constraints, the volume of the paraboloid is unbounded.  (One might say that the answer is infinity.)

So there's your answer, either 0 or infinity.

Comment: OP was asked `to find the volume of the solid generated by revolving`. Thus the graph define a surface in the $xy$-plane

Comment: Gentlemen, let us come to a consensus. Is the volume $0$ or infinite? I believe the two are different.

Comment: Follow-up comment: Your answer was not wrong. I just needed more clarification.

Comment: @MugaS.  I think I've got it.

Comment: Got it! Appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This is probably an inaccurate representation of a problem I learned in my school.

This was probably the intention of the questioner. Draw $y=2x^2$ on a $2D$ plane. Then take the part of the function in first quadrant and rotate it around y-axis. Now find the volume of the solid formed.

I'm assuming this and solving.

Basically, we want to find volume of a paraboloid. It can be done using [Second theorem of Pappus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus%27s_centroid_theorem)

Volume = Area of rotating surface * perpendicular distance of Geometric centroid of the rotating surface form the axis of rotation.

Assume a solid with height $'h'$ (along the axis of rotation) and solve using above equation.

Comment: If it is indeed solvable, could you please proceed to do so? Seeing as how I am of the opinion that it's just impossible.

Comment: Do you understand the question? Here x=0 means y-axis in 2D plane.